# Как изменить дочерние значения в GroupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть

```
void change(string first, string second, string third)
        {
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = questions[current];
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(label1);
        }
```

И я его применяю несколько раз. Когда применяешь первый раз, все работает. Но когда label1 уже создан почему-то не работает и значение label1 не меняется. Но label1 я создаю программно, поэтому не могу очистить через `label1.Text = ""`, так как его нет и я его создаю. Как мне сделать, чтобы я мог использовать это процедуру несколько раз и чтобы значение label1 всегда менялось?

Comment: Сделать лейбл полем класса?

Comment: Не могу поймать связь между аргументами метода и кодом в нём. Этот код создает лейбу и добавляет ее в панель, что написали в коде, то и происходит. А что хотите - не написали. Почему новички верят в магию телепатии, до сих пор понять не могу.

Comment: Если в лоб, то так `groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Label>().First().Text = "";`